# Why is "user acquisition" metric greater than "store listing visitors" on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, metrics, google-play-console, data-acquisition

I'm using Google Play Console Statistics to get some Analytics from my Android app. However, I am getting that "user acquisition" metric is greater than "store listing visitors" which I don't understand. How can I have more installs than visitors?

I would appreciate some help with this.

Thanks in advance,
Danny

Comment: I think you are mixing? I have no clue which of them means what, but I'd say acquisition is a user who downloaded while visitors is people who simply visited the app page but didn't download, which is logical to be greater than acquisition, am I wrong?

Comment: @DanBaruch Thanks for your comment. Indeed, there was an error in the question. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm getting more "user acquisition" than "store listing visitors".

Answer (score 1):

store listing visitors is the number of people viewing the app's store listing

user acquisition is the number of people installing the app

so in your case the number of visitors are greater than the installs.